# Google Webmaster Tools - crawl errors

Tags: google-search-console

I know that I can "clear" the crawl errors for Not Found pages, but I did completely remove the pages that I'm getting the errors for (no 301s, those pages do not exist anywhere anymore). Should I do anything about it, or will they be "fixed" automatically after some period of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you made sure you have submitted the correct sitemap(s), and that the 404s don't come from external links, eventually Googlebot will stop trying to hit those pages. But if they come from external links you should try to harvest that link-juice and 301 it somewhere (homepage or category page, if it still makes sense to do it and if you want to get link-juice from those pages)